# Longest common substring in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, substring

I'm trying to do a longest-common-substring comparison between two columns in Spark.

In theory, I could solve it with a function like this:

```py
def longest_common_substring(input_string, string_list):
    longest_substrings = []
    for string in string_list:
        longest_substring = ""
        for i in range(len(input_string)):
            for j in range(i, len(input_string)):
                if string.startswith(input_string[i:j+1]):
                    if len(input_string[i:j+1]) > len(longest_substring):
                        longest_substring = input_string[i:j+1]
        longest_substrings.append(longest_substring)
    return longest_substrings

longest_common_substring("Node 1 - 2643", 
                         ['Node 1 - 2643', 'Node ', 'Node 1 - 2643 - Node 1 A032 - 32432'])

Output:
['Node 1 - 2643', 'Node ', 'Node 1 - 2643']
```

But since I have between 100 million and several billion rows in real-world data, performance is key. A UDF would therefore probably not be an optimal solution.

Is there a way to achieve this with Spark SQL functions only?

---

## MWE

Here some example data including the column `lcs`, which represents my target column.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MWE - longest common substring") \
    .getOrCreate()

data = [
    ["AB1234|BC24412|DE34322", "AB1234|BC24412|DE9687", "AB1234|BC24412|DE"],
    ["AA2222|BB3333|CC6666", "AA2222|BD23123|EE12|ZZ929292", "AA2222|B"]
]
schema = ["pathA", "pathB", "lcs (goal)"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
```

How the data looks like:

```
+----------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
|pathA                 |pathB                       |lcs (goal)       | 
+----------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+
|AB1234|BC24412|DE34322|AB1234|BC24412|DE9687       |AB1234|BC24412|DE|
|AA2222|BB3333|CC6666  |AA2222|BD23123|EE12|ZZ929292|AA2222|B         |
+----------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was tweaking around and found a solution that works for me. Maybe it'll help someone in the future.

In the end it's way more simple than expected. It's just a `split` into arrays, followed by a `array_intersect` and finally `concat_ws` to get a string back.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_final = (
    df
    .withColumn("pathA_arr", F.split("pathA", "\\|"))
    .withColumn("pathB_arr", F.split("pathB", "\\|"))
    .withColumn("common", F.array_intersect("pathA_arr", "pathB_arr"))
    .withColumn("lcs", F.concat_ws("|", "common"))
    .drop("pathA_arr", "pathB_arr", "common")
)
```

The result looks like:

```
+----------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------+
|pathA                 |pathB                       |lcs (goal)       |lcs           |
+----------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------+
|AB1234|BC24412|DE34322|AB1234|BC24412|DE9687       |AB1234|BC24412|DE|AB1234|BC24412|
|AA2222|BB3333|CC6666  |AA2222|BD23123|EE12|ZZ929292|AA2222|B         |AA2222        |
+----------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

There is a slight difference between `lcs (goal)` and `lcs`. `|DE` is missing, but that's not a problem in my real data. I used this example because I always had a typical longest common substring function in mind.

I think the biggest advantage of this solution is, it is very fast. The additional time this causes in my real data is negligible. E.g. the whole pyspark query takes now 90s. When I tried to solve it with an `UDF`, I killed the job after 2h.

Will let this topic open for some days, if someone knows a regex solution, this could be interessting to compare.

Answer (score 0):

This should be quite efficient, as it's native Spark. It uses higher-order functions, so I would think it's slower than your option, but on the other hand, it returns exactly what's required.

```py
zipped = F.arrays_zip(F.split('pathA', r'\|'), F.split('pathB', r'\|'))
size = F.transform(zipped, lambda x: x.withField('s', F.sequence(F.lit(1), F.length(x['0']))))
df = df.withColumn('size', size)
transf = F.expr("transform(size, x -> transform(x.s, y -> struct(y s, substring(x['0'], 1, y) a, x['1'] b)))")
df = df.withColumn('transf', transf)
filt = F.expr("transform(transf, x -> sort_array(filter(x, y -> startswith(y.b, y.a)), false)[0]['a'])")
df = df.select('pathA', 'pathB', 'lcs (goal)', F.array_join(filt, '|').alias('lcs'))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +----------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
# |pathA                 |pathB                       |lcs (goal)       |lcs              |
# +----------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
# |AB1234|BC24412|DE34322|AB1234|BC24412|DE9687       |AB1234|BC24412|DE|AB1234|BC24412|DE|
# |AA2222|BB3333|CC6666  |AA2222|BD23123|EE12|ZZ929292|AA2222|B         |AA2222|B         |
# +----------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```